# Using pattern matching to typecast in SML: fun f (typ : 'Z list option ) : 'Z list

Tags: types, functional-programming, pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

As per title, trying to return a string list from the following function:

```
fun f (typ : 'Z list option ) : 'Z list =
    case typ of
        SOME x::xs' => x::xs'
```

Feedback from the terminal is as follows:

> hw2_1.sml:62.28-62.34 Error: operator and operand do not agree [circularity]
> operator domain: 'Z * 'Z list
> operand:         'Z * 'Z option list
> in expression:
> x :: xs'

> hw2_1.sml:61.5-62.34 Error: case object and rules do not agree [tycon mismatch]
> rule domain: 'Z option list
> object: 'Z list option
> in expression:
> (case typ
> of :: (SOME x,xs') => x :: xs')

It's telling me that the operator domain and operand don't agree... does that mean that **Z' list option** doesn't map to **SOME x::xs'** in terms of the type it signifies?  I'm clearly not thinking about this the right way... would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Put parenthesis around `x::xs'` in `SOME x::xs'`. because `SOME x::xs'` is interpreted by SML as `(SOME x) :: xs'` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly annotate types. You can also just write:

```
fun f typ =
    case typ of
         NONE => ...
       | SOME (x::xs) => ...
```

Or you can embed the pattern matching in the function directly:

```
fun f NONE = ...
  | f (SOME (x::xs)) = ...
```

As quoify points out, the problem you experience has to do with parentheses.

But I wanted to point out that you can make your program easier to read by making types implicit.

They will be [inferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference#Example) anyways.